# Optimization of get every nth row in a table after filter by ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, optimization, sql-server-2012

My table has 2 columns, ID1, ID2
ID1 and ID2 are one to many relationship but ID2 may not be contigous in ID1. 
Given an ID1 and a n, I should filter the table by ID1 and then return the result by every nth row.
For example, if the ID1 is 1 and after I filter it the ID2s under it are 1 2 3 4 7 8 9 11 12
and the n is 3, the result should return 1, 4, 9

I used the SQL server 2012

I wrote the following query but it runs slow. For one ID1, we have more than 1M ID2. The n we want to use in our query is from 100K to 250K. The running time for the query is currently 600ms- 1200ms which is not good for our project. Is there any method for improving the query? I want to keep every query running time below 500ms.

```
declare @now datetime = getutcdate()

declare @ID1 INT = 1518

declare @Size INT = 100000
;

select t.ID1,  t.ID2 from (

select ID1, ID2, row_number() over(order by Id2) as rownum
from table1 where ID1 = @ID1) as t
where t.rownum%@Size=1

select datediff(ms, @now, getutcdate())
```

Thanks

Comment: What rdbms, version, and edition?

Comment: sql server 2012 or later

Answer (score 0):

A clustered index on ID1 is about all you can hope for here.  That will help constrain the IO and scan to only @ID1.  Nothing else is really constant enough (@Size or ID2 row numbers).

Bear in mind that even a clustered index here might well break more than it fixes elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're set up with test data, try something like this. If it is any any faster we can work on generating @rowid based on @size

```
declare @now datetime = getutcdate()

declare @ID1 INT = 1518
--declare @Size INT = 100000
declare @rowid table(id INT) 
insert into @rowid VALUES (1),(100001),(200001),(300001),(400001),(500001),(600001),(700001),(800001),(900001),(1000001),(1100001),(1200001),(1300001),(1400001),(1500001)

select t.ID1, t.ID2 from (

select ID1
     , ID2
     , row_number() over(order by Id2) as rownum
  from table1 
 where ID1 = @ID1
) as t
where EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @rowid a WHERE a.id = t.rownum)

select datediff(ms, @now, getutcdate())
```